# Why my comment was deleted by moderators?

Tags: discussion

On the May 17 I wrote a comment under [this](https://serverfault.com/a/721704/498657) answer for the [Nginx verifying client certs only on a particular location](https://serverfault.com/questions/721572/nginx-verifying-client-certs-only-on-a-particular-location) question. I downvoted the answer, and I never downvote an answer without writing a comment explaining why do I did it. In my comment I stated that

- The answer is wrong, not applicable in a real life and I don't understand why was it upvoted so many times;
- Provide a [proof](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,173747,173838#msg-173838) from the former nginx lead developer Igor Sysoev that the feature OP asked for cannot be achieved using nginx;
- Suggest to use the second answer if the workaround it suggests is applicable.

Today I wanted to find the link to nginx forum again, open the answer I mentioned earlier and found that my comment was deleted.

May I ask, why is it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment was handled by the community bot directly without any moderators intervention as an user found your comment unkind.

I don't know the scan criteria there, as we, moderators, often handled flag on comment, but yours wasn't on a grey line for the community's bot to handle it alone at all.

For advise I would say watch the tone when you comment. The answer was useful to someone in the past, maybe it does not work, but the fact it's marked and upvoted mean it was useful.

A note; the comment before yours; [Nginx verifying client certs only on a particular location](https://serverfault.com/questions/721572/nginx-verifying-client-certs-only-on-a-particular-location/721704#comment1385153_721704) was almost a copy/paste from your comment on what you tried to told, but just told differently.

There is the printscreen. I removed the username of the one that flagged the comment, but you see the community bot that take action at the same time than the flag was raised.

[image]